# NServiceBus: Sharing Message DLLs

Tags: soa, messaging, nservicebus, distributed-system

I have been recently looking into NServiceBus, as I thought messaging would be a good way to reduce dependencies between systems. However, one of the first things that struck me is that the message publisher and all subscribers have to share the message definition DLL. What would happen in this scenario?:

Say there is one central system that handles client data. Whenever a client record is changed, it publishes a message, containing name and address. This has ten subscribers, which update their local copy of the data on receipt of the message.

One day, requirements change and one of the subscribers need the clients phone number as well. The message, the publisher, and the affected subscriber are all updated to handle the phone number, and they are all recompiled and released.

Will all nine other subscribers continue unaffected? Will they carry on as normal with the old Message DLL, or will they all need to be updated with the new DLL, recompiled and released as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NServiceBus architecture is designed to be resilient to message structure changes (especially where the changes involve adding information like in your scenario). See the [Versioning Sample](http://docs.particular.net/samples/versioning/) page on the NServiceBus site.

Comment: This is not the case. See my answer below.

Comment: It works just fine - just don't increment the AssemblyVersion attribute - use AssemblyFileVersion instead. See my comment to @hugh's answer.

Comment: Update - finally got round to trying it out: I've left the AssemblyVersion attribute untouched and it works fine!

Comment: I'm glad you got this working, however this is papering over the cracks, so to speak. The original issue you were experiencing has not gone away, you are just managing it by not allowing versionning in your messaging assembly.

Comment: I agree with @hugh.  Not changing the AssemblyVersion is a problem waiting to happen.  Indeed, I have seen this in action where two components on the same system shared a contract dll where only one was upgraded but this version number was kept the same.  Due to the installation setups using this version to keep track of who is using the same dlls on the machine, the installation failed when Windows realised they were not the same.

Answer (score 1):

It is not the case that you can handle versioning in NSB like they outline in the Versioning Sample.

You can do this if you are implementing NSB in a send/receive scenario. In this instance even though the contract is a messages DLL, the same DLL version does not need to be shared between senders and receivers. This is because providing the XML on the wire will de-serialize cleanly on the receiver end all will be well.

However, this completely breaks down in a pub-sub scenario. In this case, there is a dependency on the exact same version of the messaging assembly being shared between publisher and subscribers. This means the version, public key token etc all need to be identical. The reason for this is the subscription mechanism.

When your subscriber starts up it will send a subscription message to the publisher, who will then enter the subscription in the subscription data store. This subscription is for messages originating in a specific assembly version.

If the publisher then updates it's version of the messages DLL and receives a message which it needs to publish, it will do a lookup against the subscriptions it holds and evaluates each one in turn. Because the subscription exists for a previous version of the messages assembly the evaluation process will ignore that subscription entry, and therefore no message will be sent to the subscriber.

You need to be aware of this hard-dependency in the pub-sub scenario.

Hope this helps.

**Edit**

As of version 3.x of NServiceBus as long as your messages assembly major version is shared between publisher and subscriber then pub-sub will work as normal.

Comment: I haven't run into this problem before. Could it be avoided by having a common, high-level interface that all messages of a particular type implement (and won't change) and subscribe to it?

Comment: I have not tried this (interface as messages) but in theory this could work. As you said then you could evolve the actual messages separately for publisher/subscriber. However in practice I don't know so you would have to try it.

Comment: What you're trying to share between services is message schema, it just so happens to be represented by an assembly because that's the framework that Microsoft gives us. The solution in this case is to not implement the AssemblyVersion attribute, and always leave it at 1.0.  If you have the need to track versions, increment the AssemblyFileVersion attribute.  You can do that without disrupting the publish/subscribe mechanism.

Comment: I agree that as long as you leave the assembly versions alone you will not have any problem. However, if you are working in a CI environment often labeling/versioning automatically increments per build.

Comment: It would be nicer to not have to rely on getting the correct dll with the correct version and allow that message can be deserialize to any class since all that really matter is the schema and not the type information.

Comment: Not to hijack this thread, that is what I did with my implementation of ESB. PServiceBus(pservicebus.codeplex.com)

Comment: `As of version 3.x of NServiceBus as long as your messages assembly major version is shared between publisher and subscriber then pub-sub will work as normal.` -- Tried in v6 and even having the revision number changing was enough to break it.